# Sorting behaving differently?

Tags: java, java-8

When I try to sort a string array/list using `Comparator.naturalOrder()` it does not respect the natural order of list. Here's the snippet I used :

```
List< String > ordered = Arrays.asList( "This", "is", "the", "natural" ,"order");

System.out.println( "Natural order" );

ordered.forEach( System.out::println );

ordered.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder( ));

System.out.println( "After ordering" );

for ( String string: ordered ) {
    System.out.println( string );
}
```

Output:

```
Natural order
This
is
the
natural
order

After ordering
This
is
natural
order
the
```

Why is `Comparator.naturalOrder()` behaving such way? Same is the case when I try `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Comment: Strings are naturally ordered alphabetically. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Capital letters come before lower case letters in every charset I've ever heard of.

Comment: "it does not respect the natural order of list." - but in your example it is respecting?

Comment: Incorrect @kapex, they are ordered ASCIIbetically.

Comment: Can you change a few elements of the array such that two elements have capital letters, and two have lower case, all elements with differing initial letters? This will show you how it's sorting.

Comment: @mypetlion clearly you haven't worked with for example mainframes then, check out EBCDIC...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`naturalOrder` means *according* to `Comparator` or plain String comparison order, *not* source's encounter order. These are totally different things.

May be a Stream of `Integer` would be easier to understand:

```
Stream.of(3,4,1,2)...
```

encounter order is `3, 4, 1, 2`

sorted order is `1, 2, 3, 4` - meaning **naturally** sorted (via `Comparator.naturalOrder()`)

Comment: I totally misunderstood  `naturalOrder()` then. I thought it would respect the order items are inserted.

Comment: @stackFan right, it's Comparators natural order, not encounter's natural order

Comment: @stackFan and btw it's not "inserted", but "traversed" anyway - think of a `Set` and a tenth inserted element, when traversing this `Set` it does not mean it will be seen as the 10-th one

Comment: The name `naturalOrder` is so confusing though. Makes me think otherwise. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @stackFan there is nothing confusing about it. `String`s have a natural order, `Integer` values have a natural order, etc. It's also explained in [the documentation of `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Comparable.html): “*This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its natural comparison method.*” That’s also the reason why `Comparator.naturalOrder()` only works with `Comparable` elements. When you want a comparator without any effect, you can use `(a,b) -> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`naturalOrder()` returns a `Comparator` that compares `Comparable` objects in natural order.

In your example, it is comparing the entries of the collection in dictionary order. (u*sing the ASCII value for each letter*).